# django-allauth socialaccount "full" logout?

Tags: django, django-allauth

I am working on what might become a sort-of kiosk app.  I am new to python and django but it is rolling along.  My allauth flow for signup uses either a social login (Google for the moment) or a "local" email address & password.

If I login with a Google account then logout I am redirected to the sign-in page, cool.  The thing is I have not *really* been logged out of the Google account.  If I click the social login link then I am back in the user area with no password challenge.

Does allauth have a way to logout and have the social auth token removed?  Do I need to catch the logout signal and find/delete the token myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there is a [built-in solution](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/release-notes.html#id108).  There is an `action` parameter that can be given the value "reauthenticate".  Being new to this stuff I am not positive that I have added it in the python/django way but I have edited the template:

```
myProject/templates/allauth/socialaccount/snippets/provider_list.html
```

and added `action=reauthenticate"` to the social auth href line a la:

```
{% load socialaccount %}

{% get_providers as socialaccount_providers %}

{% for provider in socialaccount_providers %}
{% if provider.id == "openid" %}
{% for brand in provider.get_brands %}
<li>
  <a title="{{brand.name}}" 
     class="socialaccount_provider {{provider.id}} {{brand.id}}" 
     href="{% provider_login_url provider.id openid=brand.openid_url process=process action='reauthenticate' %}"
     >{{brand.name}}</a>
</li>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
<li>
  <a title="{{provider.name}}" class="socialaccount_provider {{provider.id}}" 
     href="{% provider_login_url provider.id process=process scope=scope auth_params=auth_params %}">{{provider.name}}</a>
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

That seems to do the trick.

Comment: From the docs Aug2019: "you can pass along an action parameter with value reauthenticate to indicate that you want the user to be re-prompted for authentication even if they already signed in before. For now, this is supported by Facebook, Google and Twitter only."

Comment: Also from the docs: "You must set `AUTH_PARAMS['access_type']` to `offline` in order to receive a refresh token on first login and on reauthentication requests." https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/providers.html#google